# How to get current time in minutes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to display current time in minutes i tried below code

```
$scope.getDatetime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                    console.log($scope.getDatetime/60)
```

But its not working correctly..

Comment: what do you mean by current time in minutes?

Comment: Can you replace your "But its not working correctly" with something like "But instead of [expected result], it returns [returned result]". It's much easier for us to understand what you want that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not about angular JS, you can achieve it using JS itself.

```
var currentMinute = new Date().getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/) and convert hours into minutes,

```js
var app = angular.module("app", ["angularMoment"]);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
     $scope.m = moment(Date.now());
     $scope.minutes = ($scope.m.hour()*60) + $scope.m.minute();
    
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="moment.js@*" data-semver="2.1.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.1.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    Time is :
    <h1>{{m}}</h1> Minutes is :
    <h1>{{minutes}}</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getDateTime = new Date().getMinutes();
```

Javascript date getMinutes() method returns the minutes in the specified date according to local time. The value returned by getMinutes() is an integer between 0 and 59.